# Google APP Script suddenly exporting PDF as text/html

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a strange problem and am hoping someone can guide. We have been using the following script for a long time with no issue, converts sheet into PDF and stores it into the drive. Now for some reason the file being created is a text/html file in PDF format. I am not sure why this is happening now nothing else has changed on our side.

```js
    function convertSpreadsheetToPdf(email, spreadsheetId, sheetName, pdfName) 
     {
        var spreadsheet = spreadsheetId ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId) :
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId ? spreadsheetId : spreadsheet.getId()  
        var sheetId = sheetName ? spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId() : null;  
        var pdfName = pdfName ? pdfName : spreadsheet.getName();
        var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).getParents();
        var folder = parents.hasNext() ? parents.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder();
        var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

        var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      // Print either the entire Spreadsheet or the specified sheet if optSheetId is provided
      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=letter'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
       var options = {
       headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),}
  
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
       var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
       folder.createFile(blob);
  
  }
```

Comment: If you open the file (as html), does it look like the contents of the spreadsheet, or something totally different? If the request is failing for some reason you might be getting an HTML error page in the response.

Comment: Does it happen for only one certain file? Mind that it should be `  var options = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()} 
  } ` and not `var options = {
       headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),}`.

Comment: the opened file looks like the spreadsheet but in html/text, it is happening for all the files that we run this script

Comment: sorry I am not able to open it as an HTML, it is saved as PDF but inside the PDF is all HTML

Comment: I did more research and this is happening to ONLY 1 user and the sheets he creates among our multiple users, not sure why

Comment: Maybe the user has corrupt pdf files? Can you provide a test copy of the original file and of the resulting file after conversion?